# Proof of Dependence of Random Variables

Tags: probability

Is the following proof valid?

Let $X$ and $Y$ be jointly continuous random variables such that the joint density function is given by 
$$
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
ye^{-(x+y)} & \text{ for } x>0, y>0  \\
0 & \text{ otherwise } 
\end{cases}
$$

Then $X$ and $Y$ are dependent.

Proof

Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables. Let the probability density function of $X$ be given by $f_X(x) = e^x$. Let the probability density function of $Y$ be given by $f_Y(y) = ye^y$.
$$ f_X(x)f_Y(y) = (e^{-x})(ye^{-y})= ye^{-(x+y)} $$
Jointly continuous random variables are independent if and only if 
$ f(x,y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y) \hspace{8 px} \forall \hspace{7 px} x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus, to prove that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, it suffices to show that there exist some pair of real numbers $x, y$ such that 
$f(x, y) \neq f_X(x) f_Y(y)$. Suppose $x = -1$, and suppose $y = -1$. Then 
$f(x, y) = 0$. We also have that $ f_X(-1)f_Y(-1) = -e^2 \neq 0 $. So $X$ and $Y$ are dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not valid. You are failing to account for the support.

\begin{align*} 
f(x,y) &= ye^{-(x+y)} \mathbf{1}[x \ge 0 \text{ and } y \ge 0] \\
&= ye^{-(x+y)} \mathbf{1}[x \ge 0] \cdot  \mathbf{1}[y \ge 0] \\
&= \underbrace{\left( e^{-x} \cdot \mathbf{1}[x \ge 0] \right)}_{f_X(x)}  \underbrace{\left( y e^{-y} \cdot \mathbf{1}[y \ge 0] \right)}_{f_Y(y)}
\end{align*}

The marginal densities above are identified by integrating the joint pdf e.g. $$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y) \; dy$$

Comment: Is there another pair for which $f(x,y) \neq f_X(x) f_Y(y)$, or are the variables actually independent?

Comment: @Wafflebaby They are independent.

Comment: I see how this works where the product is nonnegative. I don't quite see how it works when the product is negative.